# How to give delay using simple jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am using this script,

```
$('.ui-group').addClass('animated fadeInLeft');.
```

Actually i need to give delay for this animation using JQuery. We are using animate.css plugin and its class. so usual delay on script is not working.

Any solution for this?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout

Comment: @Alex its not consistent also have some issue that it works only once

Comment: Then you should maybe add those information to your question, dont you think? Are we people supposed to guess what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: we have given the full detail. please check now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this,

```
$('.ui-group').addClass('animated fadeInLeft').delay(500);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
$('.ui-group').addClass('animated fadeInLeft').delay(800);
```

Look [here](https://api.jquery.com/delay/) for example or in snippet at the end.

```js
$("button").click(function() {
  $("div.first").slideUp(300).delay(800).fadeIn(400);
  $("div.second").slideUp(300).fadeIn(400);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>delay demo</title>
  <style>
    div {
      position: absolute;
      width: 60px;
      height: 60px;
      float: left;
    }
    .first {
      background-color: #3f3;
      left: 0;
    }
    .second {
      background-color: #33f;
      left: 80px;
    }
  </style>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <p>
    <button>Run</button>
  </p>
  <div class="first"></div>
  <div class="second"></div>



</body>

</html>
```